# Angular 6+ - key event handling with input text filter

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, keyevent, textinput

I'm working on an angular app in which we have defined a text filter component.

In the component HTML file

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterText" (input)="valueChange()" (keydown.enter)="myFunction ($event)" />
```

Current behaviour when user enters a text and hit enter below is the order of execution.

> 1. myFunction ()
> 2. valueChange()

Expected is *valueChange()* to be called before *myFunction()* .

Any help is much appreciated.

This happens by default in IE11+  and in rare cases for other browsers.

Comment: You can probably set a timeout in the myFunction and then the code there will be executed after some time ? `setTimeout()` if you want to try this I can give you an example in an answer.

Comment: You really don't want both `[(ngModel)]="filterText"` and `(input)="valueChange()"`. Use a setter for `filterText`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyup` event like this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterText" (input)="valueChange()" (keyup.enter)="myFunction($event)" />
```

Actually the order is: `keydown` , `input` , `keyup`

Comment: I believe the keydown event will be triggered for all keys but, I want it only for 'enter'.
We can still filter by key code. But I may need to check.

Comment: @mperle I edited the code. You can use keys in `keyup` exactly like `keydown`

Comment: @mperle Also I beileve pressing the `enter` key will not fire `input` event. But I haven't tested.